# ImageUrl attribute in Hyperlink

Tags: gridview, hyperlink, imageurl

In my gridview I have added the Hyperlink with ImageUrl attribute based on condition:

```
ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Link").ToString()) ?
         "/Images/email-grey.gif" : "/Images/email-orange.gif")%>'
```

If the value of field "Link" of my query is null I show the image

```
email-grey.gif
```

else

```
email-orange.gif
```

But I need another additional condition, when the field "Sending" of my query is equal to 1 I need show the image:

```
email-open-orange.gif
```

Here my code, but the error is, can you help me ?

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Link").ToString()) ? "/Images/email-grey.gif" : 
                                   Eval("Sending").ToString().Equals("1") ? "/Images/email-open-orange.gif" : "/Images/email-orange.gif"))%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Link").ToString()) ? "/Images/email-grey.gif" : 
                                   Eval("Sending").ToString().Equals("1") ? "/Images/email-open-orange.gif" : "/Images/email-orange.gif")%>'
```